# ARC: copy method

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a page where autorefresh happens and a method is called. I do a copy of the CXMLELement in that method , and use it. My project is under ARC.

```
(void)update:(CXMLElement)element
{
 CXMLElement *node = [element copy];
 passToAnotherMethod(node);
}
```

(or)

```
(void)update:(CXMLElement)element
{
 self.xml = [element copy]; // xml is a strong propery in class which will be used in other methods

}
```

When I use Allocations tool i see the element that is copied is not released at all. What could be the issue here.What should I do to release the node that is copied everytime. Please help.

Comment: How are you using the 'node' after this line of code?

Comment: Please could you include all the code for this method. Just showing us this line doesn't really help, on it's own it's just a line of code that doesn't really matter.

Comment: am passing the node to another method where it is parsed.

Comment: Have two implementations in different classes, where 1. I will pass the node to another method 2. Where i assign a strong variable pointer and then use in other methods.

Comment: If i do not do copy, then i get a crash

Answer (score 0):

When you copy element it means that you are creating a new pointer for the same object hence node acts as new object. As soon as the current execution finishes it will be automatically released if there are now new reference to the same object.(If in a method you are sending node instance to another object that another object is also refers to node's pointer)

Comment: But, am not seeing the node being released for some reason. So, the memory keeps on increasing.

Comment: Is node referred from somewhere else?

Comment: If that is not referred anywhere else why are you copying? Can I have some more code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Two things you should consider the place where `update:(CXMLElement)element` is called,the actual owner of element is that particular class. Eventhough you used it in `update:(CXMLElement)element` the reference count increases by one. You can try the following methods

1. Declare the property xml as `weak` and declare the element where it actually created is also declare `weak`
2. Don't use any callback from `update:(CXMLElement)element` which pass element as a return type to its actual caller(That should make a retain cycle)

**EDIT :**
 Please try

```
 -(void)update:(CXMLElement *)element    
    {   
       passToAnotherMethod(element);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks.The element that is getting passed to update method is not retained by the owner also. It justs gets the data from server, converts into XML and sends it to the update method. Since this method is being called everytime during autorefresh, I think it creates a leak.

Comment: did you try manually set the value of element = nil before autorefresh??

Comment: I do not have control over that, it is a framework from where the update method gets called. Still am not getting why ARC does not handle this.

Comment: But that is crashing if we pass to another method without copying element

Comment: I don't know why its crashing then can u try  (note the * before element)                                                (void)update:(CXMLElement *)element
{
 CXMLElement *node = element;
 passToAnotherMethod(node);
}

Comment: U mean to say not to copy, then who will own it

Comment: The class who created will own it ,and hence reference count not get increased.Then avoid possible leaks

Comment: But, the class which created it does not have any retain statement. It  just gets the data and parses it to XML and passes it to my class method. Means, there is no instance variable present in the owner class

Comment: There is no need for an instance variable there when you assign element to any other object or passing it to a method then it will automatically get copied